# Json Return multiple fields

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, autocomplete

I am pretty new to JavaScript, Ajax, Json, Jquery . . but trying to make my way.

I have an application in MVC5/C# where I use autocomplete for a search box.  That part works great.  After the user selects an item from the autocomplete box, I want to use the ID field of that item, to bring back and populate the rest of the view.  I am almost there. . .

This is where I return my Json from the controller to populate the autocomplete (which works).

```
return { label: item.Old_ItemID + "    " + item.ItemDescription, value: item.Old_ItemID };
```

Being unfamiliar but winging it - looks like there is a label and value in the return.  I modified the label so that the user can also see the description during the search.  And that works.

But, I also need a second field (SuppliesID).   How do I get that?  I tried a small mod below:

```
return { label: item.Old_ItemID + "    " + item.ItemDescription, value: item.Old_ItemID, id: item.SuppliesID };
```

I thought I could add another variable (id) and grab it.  But, that didn't work.

How can I get the second needed field in the return?

This is my controller function to get the Json results

```
var checkItems = db.ICS_Supplies.Where(x => x.Supplies_ID == id).ToList();
        return Content(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(checkItems), "application/json");
```

I am assuming that checkItems should bring back every field in the matching record.  But how do I get to it?

Answer (score 0):

Your return statement looks like valid javascript. I'm not sure what library or framework you're using for your controller, but should your "x.Supplies_ID == id" actually be "x.id == id"?

The object should have the id number listed under the name "id" since that's what you called it in the return statement.